# Torricelli's Law and number of holes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation

Trying to determine if the number of holes at the bottom of a bucket will change time it takes for water to empty the bucket.

Looking at the equation, it would seem that as long as the area of the hole(s) are the same, the time for the water to flow out should be the same?

Bucket 1 with one hole of a certain area vs Bucket 2 with two holes, but each hole is half the area of the hole in bucket 1 vs Bucket 3 with four holes, each hole is a quarter of the area of the hole in bucket 1.

Is it the size of the hole the water flows out, regardless of how many there are?  So, half the size (but twice as many) would still produce a time 1.41 times longer?  Quarter the size (but with 4 holes) would still produce a time 2 times longer?

Comment: If you make the hole too small, due to surface tension, water may not flow out at all.

Comment: this is something you could easily do a home experiment with to find out

Answer (score 1):

In a world without friction, where water is a perfect fluid, as long as the total area of the holes in the bucket is the same, the rate of water flowing out would be the same. However, since friction exists, and water is far from being a perfect liquid, the bucket with the smaller holes would have a lower rate of water flowing out since the water would be experiencing energy losses.

Comment: “In a world without friction, where water is a perfect fluid” — in such conditions *it's impossible to have water in a bucket with a hole at the bottom of it*. (In other words, water would flow out *instantly, at once.)*

Comment: @MarianD : I would expect this would to still respect law of inertia, Newton's second law, and restricted relativity, such that mass could not flow instantly.